# How can I get a gwt-maps-3.0 api jar compatible with java 1.5 compiler

Tags: google-maps, gwt

I am working for a large company that changes slowly. We are deploying to a Weblogic 10.2 environment, and are stuck with java 1.5. That is not a problem with GWT libraries, but the downloaded version of gwt-maps-3.0.2b.gwt22.jar we have pulled down was built with a 1.6 compiler. Does anyone know if a 1.5 built version is available?

Baring that, is it possible to rebuild with the 1.5 compiler, since the source is in the jar? If so, does anyone have a build script to do so?

-- Some additional info
We are trying to upgrade some existing code, This is the first error that they ran into offshore. The compile error tat they got was:
o   Error: “class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0”

I checked the jar file using the following method.

1. built the following program:

   import java.io.*;

   public class CheckVersion {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           for (int i=0; i < args.length; ++i) {
               checkVersion(args[i]);
           }
       }

   ```
   private static void checkVersion(String classFileName) throws IOException {
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(classFileName));

       int magicNo = in.readInt();
       if (magicNo != 0xCAFEBABE) {
           System.err.println(classFileName + " is not a valid class file name");
           return;
       }
       int minor = in.readUnsignedShort();
       int major = in.readUnsignedShort();
       System.out.println(classFileName + ": " + major +"." + minor);
       in.close();
   }
   ```

   }
2. extracted the jar file eg. "jar xvf gwt-maps3-0.2b.jar"
3. ran the following command: "find . -name *.class | xargs java CheckVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | sort -u"

Comment: The rearme file for the 3.8 pre-release has a 1.5 or better compiler requirement, but was also built with a 1.6 compiler.

Comment: I was able to eventually get this to work, but I had to modify the source to remove the 1.6 annotation. As best I can tell it did not cause any issues to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download sources from google code :

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/source/checkout

-- No this does not work. All versions on the page were built with 1.6

Comment: My bad I forgot about annotation format. You can try codeweaver to alter bytecode and make the 1.6 jar compatible with 1.5 VM. I dit it for small library and it worked. I don't know if it will succeed with Google Maps api, also I'm not sure if license allow it.

Comment: This might be a tactic of last resort, but I would suspect that we will run into a bycode problem at some point. Also, it could not be just done to the jar, it would have to be done to every class file in the jar.

Comment: Its retroweaver : http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/. It hopefully applies to a full jar content. An usage sample : http://i-proving.com/2008/11/18/weaving-our-way-back-to-java-1-4/. .

Comment: Anyway, with source code, you can write a script that do the @Override manipulation and recompile with javac 1.5. As said i had same kind of issue with old OSGi runtime and it was a pain :/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by downloading the source, commenting out the @Override annotations which in 1.5 require that method in the parent have an implementation, and recompiling the module.